# Proguard error: Multiple dex files define Activity

Tags: android, ant, proguard

I've heard that lots of people get this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lfoo.bar.MyActivity;
```

However none of the solutions I found on StackOverflow works for me.

I read that this error may be caused when you include multiple times in the project the same library, but the strange thing is that foo.bar.MyActivity is defined in only one library, and that library is included only once in my project.

Please note that foo.bar.MyActivity is defined in an Android library, not in a jar.

Another strange thing is that I can compile and run the app correctly if I turn ProGuard off: the error shows up only after the pre-dexing done by Proguard (so the second one in the compilation process).

Here's the complete stack trace of the error that proguard gives:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lfoo.bar.MyActivity;
Merged dex A (4111 defs/3053.8KiB) with dex B (47 defs/47.0KiB). Result is 4158 defs/3628.2KiB. Took 0.6s
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve my issue?

PS: I use Ant to compile the app.

Thanks a lot for your time.

**Additional Infos:**
I use Netbeans with nbandroid to build the app

Answer (score 1):

> try this hope it may solve your problem

I had the same problem, quite weird because it was happening only when using Eclipse (but it was OK with Ant). This is how I fixed it:

Right click on the Project Name
Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In Java Build Path, go to the tab Order and Export

Uncheck your .jar library

Only sometimes: In Order and Export tab I did not have any jar library there, so I have unchecked Android Private Libraries item. Now my project is running.

Comment: can u please tell me what is your maxtargetsdk

Comment: and check out your dependencies

Comment: I don't have a maxTargetSDK

Comment: Put all your jars under libs/ and clean your projects.

Comment: I think that the problem isn't related to the jars of the libraries, but it's about the .jar files that Ant generates from the Java code. I have no control over them, since they are generated every time I compile the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63075/discussion-between-abhishek-chaubey-and-spotlight).